# file_get_html(), returning -> plaintext with another encoding

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so, i fetch some text between a  tag, and i use file_get_html, now, the text is returned with different encoding, this is what i do:

```
$name = $dom->find('h1');
$name = $name[0]->plaintext; 
$name = html_entity_decode($name);
$name = utf8_decode($name);
```

html_entity_decode does remove most of the trash, but i still get signs such as â€ from '–' i found out this was an encoding issue, so i use utf8_decode, which changes the â€ to ?, but how do i get it back to its original ´-´value? is there any quick fix?

I am not very enlightend with the encoding and such, any help is greatly apriciated

Comment: No it is not the same question.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post an entire method and maybe a var_dump() of $name possibly in each step.

Comment: These two dashes are different symbols. In eyes of PHP they are like two different letters. If you want to replace one with another, you need to use `str_replace` with character itself or `preg_replace` with it's code.